# Saving text from a textbox to global string. Best way to use the save?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, global-variables

(Using WPF Application / WPF UserControl)

It is possible to use the below code to save the text from a textbox to a global string.

```
private void commentBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.cmd01 = commentBox.Text;

    //always save on every input change??
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

But what i wonder about now, is that in this case, the `save` is called on each text change. So if i understood correct, it saves now on each key pressed.

Could i do this in a more clean way? For example when the user leaves the focus from the textbox or something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggested: subscribe to [UIElement.LostFocus Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus.aspx) or [Keyboard.LostKeyboardFocus Attached Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostkeyboardfocus.aspx) of your `TextBox` and do the save there.

```
private void commentBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

or

```
private void commentBox_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use WPF you might as well take advantage of the Binding infrastructure for this sort of thing. You can use an UpdateSourceTrigger of LostFocus

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Settings.Command01, 
                        Mode=OneWayToSource, 
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
```

C#:

```
 public class BindableSettings : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
         public string Command01
         {
                get { return Properties.Settings.Default.cmd01; }
                set 
                {
                      if (Properties.Settings.Default.cmd01 == value)
                           return;

                      NotifyPropertyChanged("Command01");
                }
         }

         public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string prop)
         {
             Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
             //Raise INPC event here...
         }

    }
```